# Database Update in VBA

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ms-access

```
Sub uoload_data()
    Dim s(40) As Integer
    Dim Row As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    For Row = 7 To 39
        s(i) = Sheets("Data").Cells(Row, 5).Value
        i = i + 1
    Next
    Dim cn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim strSql As String
    Dim strConnection As String
    Dim AppPath As String
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    AppPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=C:\Users\devi\Desktop\Ability.accdb;"
    cn.Open strConnection
    strSql = "INSERT INTO MyTable Values ('" & s(0) & " ',    
    '" & s(1) & " ','" & s(2) & " ','" & s(3) & " ' )"
    Set rs = cn.Execute(strSql)
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

I have a excel sheet of 40 field. I would like to update all field to access database. while insert record into database i am using insert into statement. In the mean time i need to write all fields of array into insert into statement. So please help me out to compact statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Join()` here

```
strSql = "INSERT INTO MyTable Values ('" & Join(s, "','") & "')"
```

The values in `s()` are integers, but you're wrapping the values in single-quotes, so are your DB columns text-type?

If they are numeric columns then you should drop the single-quotes.

Comment: Yes my column is text type if a declare a variable st as string varibale & i would like to use join function with varibale st. in the mean time its showing error "Invalid Procedure call or argument"
st = Join(s, "&")

Comment: My bad - you will need to declare `Dim s(40) As String`

Comment: Doesn't VBA ADODB support stored procedures? Why not use those instead?